# Environmental variables - how to check in runtime which command is executed

Tags: cmd, path, environment-variables, exe

I have got multiple env. variables set in PATH; I am also using .bat files to set these before certain activities. It's obvious that some variables may be then duplicated ex. *grep* may be defined more than once (in cygwin and MSYS2) For sure there is a way to check which file i have executing using specific command and which other files are available, based on PATH. Could you please suggest the way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest to kpathsea on windows is where

```
where /t cmd.* grep.* notepad.*
```

[image]

to check in the path use

```
where /t $path:cmd*
```

[image]

**for a listing of most possibilities try**

`where /t $path:*>commands.txt`

Comment: Thank you very very much! Thats the tool i was looking for :)